# Как правильно? (1)

Tags: грамматика

*Пять стульев оказалось/оказались поврежденными/повреждены.*

Comment: Почитайте тут про согласование: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: Не за что, Елена)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректные варианты из предложенных пар:
*Пять стульев оказались поврежденными.* || Оказались вот такими. Значение прилагательного. Характеристика.
*Пять стульев оказались (кем-то) повреждены.* || Причастие. Акцент на действии — что кто-то их повредил.

Comment: Большое спасибо ща ответ и ща то, что указали части речи. Сразу всё стало просто и понятно.

Comment: В первом примере тоже причастие, но в качестве прилагательного.

Comment: Спасибо здесь оформляется так: если ответ полезен, то треугольник вверх (это как спасибо), а если решает проблему, то кроме треугольника ещё и зелёная галочка (это как большое спасибо).